# Nifi Consume Kafka adds a fake record

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

Am building a Nifi flow which reads from a Kafka topic but, when I check the output I always find an empty record in addition to the real record like below

```
[{"ID":0,"SE_URL":"","STATUS":null,"STORE_DATE":-10},{"ID":76,"SE_URL":"76","STATUS":"76","STORE_DATE":1578914982000}]
```

am not sure where this record is getting introduced. any suggestions ?

[image]

Comment: did you look in the queue if your reccords are correct just after the consumKafka processor ?

Comment: Maybe you should add more data to your Kafka messages like the host it can from, and the time it was created. Who says that the record was not already in the topic? Have you used console consumer to look?

Comment: @cricket_007 I cleared eveything and still same result

Comment: i think the problem come from your producer. can you create a producer in nifi and test with it ?

Comment: Again, there seems to be some external producer sending that data. Even if you cleared the topic, that doesn't stop producers from running. Please show the output of the console consumer